# javascript: in a chain, how to get size of previous array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, this, method-chaining

When chaining filter and reduce, how to get the size of the filtered array? I need that size for tailoring responsive design CSS.
My (simplified) code, uses the 3rd and 4th parameters of the callback:

```
json.articles
.filter(a => keep(a,name))
.reduce((el, a,i,t) =>
    i===0? DOMtag('section',{'class':`media${t.length}`})
        .appendChild(DOMtag(`article`, content(a,0))).parentElement
    : el.appendChild(DOMtag(`article`, content(a,i))).parentElement,
    null);
```

or, even simpler (thanks to luc and his lazy evaluation suggestion below):

```
json.articles
.filter(a => keep(a,name))
.reduce((el, a,i,t) =>
    (el || DOMtag('section',{'class':`media${t.length}`}))
        .appendChild(DOMtag(`article`, content(a,i))).parentElement,
    null);
```

Both code work, but if someone has an idea about binding `this` somehow, it would be possible to use the initial value of the accumulator, such as:

```
json.articles
.filter(a => keep(a,name))
.reduce((el, a) =>
    el.appendChild(DOMtag(`article`, content(a,i))).parentElement,
    DOMtag('section',{'class':`media${this.length}`}));
```

Any idea?

Comment: the 4th argument in the reducer function  is the source array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: @kunal_bohra. Yes, this is how I am using it in my 1st code, but available only in the callback, not in reduce (can't be used for initial value).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to have access to the filtered array length at the moment of passing the default value of `reduce` since the expression is evaluated before `reduce` is called.

You can, though, simplify the contents of your function as follows:

```js
// Sample data
const json = {articles: [{name: 'test'},{},{name: 'test2'},{},]};
// functional helper function to illustrate the example
function DOMTag(tagName, {content, className}) {
  const tag = document.createElement(tagName);

  if (content) {
    tag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
  }
  if (className) {
    tag.className = className;
  }
  return tag;
}

// Start of actual answer code:
const section = json.articles
  .filter(a => a.name)
  .map(a => DOMTag(`article`, {content: a.name}))
  .reduce((p, c, i, a) =>
    (p || DOMTag('section',{className:`media${a.length}`}))
      .appendChild(c).parentElement
      , null);

section.className = `media${section.childNodes.length}`

// Validation
console.log(section.outerHTML);
```

Another option that would be clean is to set the `className` outside of the chain:

```js
// Sample data
const json = {articles: [{name: 'test'},{},{name: 'test2'},{},]};
// functional helper function to illustrate the example
function DOMTag(tagName, content) {
  const tag = document.createElement(tagName);
  if (content) {
    tag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
  }
  return tag;
}

// Start of actual answer code:
const section = json.articles
  .filter(a => a.name)
  .map(el => DOMTag('article', el.name))
  .reduce((p,c) => (p.appendChild(c), p), DOMTag('section'))

section.className = `media${section.childNodes.length}`

// Validation
console.log(section.outerHTML);
```

Option2: use a function to abstract the creation of the container:

```js
// Sample data
const json = {articles: [{name: 'test'},{},{name: 'test2'},{},]};
// functional helper function to illustrate the example
function DOMTag(tagName, {content, className}) {
  const tag = document.createElement(tagName);
  if (content) {
    tag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
  }
  if (className) {
    tag.className = className;
  }
  return tag;
}

// Start of actual answer code:

function section(children) {
  const section = DOMTag('section', {
    className: `media${children.length}`
  });
  children.forEach(c => section.appendChild(c));
  return section;
}

const s = section(
  json.articles
    .filter(a => a.name)
    .map(el => DOMTag('article', {content: el.name}))
)

// Validation
console.log(s.outerHTML);
```

Option 3: more functions! If you *absolutely* must use reduce:

```js
// Sample data
const json = {articles: [{name: 'test'},{},{name: 'test2'},{},]};
// functional helper function to illustrate the example
function DOMTag(tagName, {content, className}) {
  const tag = document.createElement(tagName);
  if (content) {
    tag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
  }
  if (className) {
    tag.className = className;
  }
  return tag;
}

// Start of actual answer code:

function defaultSection() {
  let m = false;
  return (a = []) => {
    if (!m) {
      m = DOMTag('section', {className: `media${a.length}`});
    }
    return m;
  };
}

const section = json.articles
  .filter(a => a.name)
  .map(el => DOMTag('article', {content: el.name}))
  .reduce((p,c,i,a) => {
    p(a).appendChild(c);
    return p;
  }, defaultSection())();

// Validation
console.log(section.outerHTML);
```

Comment: There is a way to pass the array to the callback (a synchronous callback), hence I believe that there should be a way to bind `this` to that array. Your workarounds #2 and #3 are intersting (#1 is not chainable), but not much better than my own first solution.

Comment: That's a fair point. I don't think you can use `bind` in the way you are thinking but you can take advantage of lazy evaluation of boolean expressions to simplify your initial code. Update the answer with a new option that might be interesting as well.

Comment: I don't understand why that answer has been downvoted. At least the comment above is very useful.